python: logging not write in file & ask best practice for logging in multi-file project
I would like to implement some log in one of my projects. Two problems exist.
first: how to setup my logging system?
second: with my current setup logs are shown in the console but are not written in the file ( it creates the file but the file is always empty )
my current setup is:

write logging's config in a dict object in a file
import that file into the main file of the project
config the logging using the dictConifg function
start a logger using getLogger(__name__) for every file
use that logger

is this setup correct and best practice?
why logging creates the file but does not write logs into it?
here is my files:
main.py
import logging.config
from time import sleep
from legging_config import LOGGING_CONFIGS
from something import Something

logging.config.dictConfig(LOGGING_CONFIGS)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logger.info("Application started.")
    nothing_1 = Something()
    sleep(1)
    nothing_2 = Something()
    logger.warning("Application finished.")

something.py
import logging
from time import sleep

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class Something:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        logger.debug("Create something.")
        sleep(1)

legging_config.py
LOGGING_CONFIGS = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        "format": {"format": "%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"}
    },
    "handlers": {
        "console": {
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "formatter": "format",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stdout",
        },
        "file": {
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": "data/logs/main.log",
            "mode": "a",
            "formatter": "format",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "logger": {
            "handlers": ["console", "file"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": False,
        }
    },
    "root": {"handlers": ["console"], "level": "DEBUG"},
}

Console output
2024-04-21 09:35:53,469 - __main__ - INFO - Application started.
2024-04-21 09:35:53,470 - something - DEBUG - Create something.
2024-04-21 09:35:55,471 - something - DEBUG - Create something.
2024-04-21 09:35:56,473 - __main__ - WARNING - Application finished.

main.log



First, you have a logger named logger in your configuration dictionary, but you're fetching the logger by module name using getLogger(__name__). This means your specific configuration for logger is not being used unless you actually, explicitely call getLogger("logger").
Next, your root logger is configured to use only the console handler at its DEBUG level. That means any logs captured by the root logger or any logger that propagates to the root will not be sent to the file handler, simply because there's none configured.
These issues together results in your log file being empty, since your loggers rely on propagation (the default behavior unless you explicitly set propagate to False), and since the root logger does not have the file handler attached, logs do not get written to the file.
As a fix, just edit your config to include file handler:
"root": {
    "handlers": ["console", "file"],
    "level": "DEBUG",
}


Thanks a lot. So based on your answer, I don't need the logger and need to add the file handler to the root logger. am I right? Something like this
"root": {"handlers": ["console", "file"], "level": "DEBUG"},

Yes, that should be sufficient
